# Azure Subscription Tags: How to delete an empty tag value?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Azure portal allows us to create a tag containing empty value for any resource/resource group (As seen in attached screenshot, 'test' tag is created with empty value).

[image]

If I want to delete the tag value i.e empty value, It is not possible to delete that value from [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/deletevalue), it shows this error message.

```
{
      "message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
                'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/tagNames/test/tagValues/?api-version=2017-05-10'."
}
```

Suppose for example I create a tag in one resource having tag name '**department**' and tag value '**finance**':

```
{
    'department': 'finance'
}
```

and for other resource I create a tag with same tag name and empty value:

```
{
    'department': ''
}
```

Now I want to delete this empty tag value. In that case I can't use  [Tags - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/delete) method because I can't delete tag name here as this tag name is associated to other resource.
So is it possible to delete the empty tag value?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong method. Try using [Tags - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/delete) which only requires you to use `tagName`.

The [Tags - Delete Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/deletevalue) you referred to would indeed require both a `tagValue` and `tagName`.

So in your case, the REST request would be:

```
DELETE 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tagNames/test?api-version=2018-02-01
```

Comment: Hi Theirry, I have modified my question according to a certain scenario, can you help me in that case.

Comment: Hi Jagrati, for me to help you, could you please explain why you are using an old API-version? Did you check whether the "2017-05-10" version for tagNames exists as I was unable to find such a version.

Comment: Using the latest version "2018-02-01", scenario remains the same we can create empty tag values for resources.